# Django and Ajax trouble with POST address

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, post, filter

I stumbled upon a very peculiar problem with Django and JQuery/Ajax
There are addresses in URLs:

```
url(r'^app/insert$', Insert.as_view(), name="insert"),
url(r'^app/insert_ajax$', Insert_Ajax.as_view(), name="insert_ajax"),
url(r'^app/edit/(?P<id>\d+)/$', Edit.as_view(), name="edit"),
```

As you can see, they're all object-based views. There is also a model:

```
class TheModel(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(AnotherModel, related_name="anotherModel")
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(ListOfAttributes, related_name="attributes", blank=True)
```

and a form based upon given model:

```
class TheModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TheModel
```

So the deal is that attribute has to change (filter) according to given item. There is a JQuery that handles that:

```
    var change_attribute = function(){

    var selected_item_id = $("#selected_item_id").val();
    $.post("insert_ajax",{"method":"get_attributes","item":$("#id_item").val()}, function( data ) {
        $("#id_attributes").empty();
        $.each(data,function(index, value){
            if(value['id'] == selected_item_id){
                $("#id_attributes").append("<option selected='selected' value='"+ value['id'] +"'>"+value['name']+"</option>");
            }else{
                $("#id_attributes").append("<option value='"+ value['id'] +"'>"+value['name']+"</option>");
            }
        });
    });

}
```

And this goes straight to Ajax view:

```
class CallDropAjax(View):

    def post(self, request):
        method = request.POST.get('method', None)
        context = {}
        if method:
            try:
                context = getattr(self, method)(request)
            except AttributeError as e:
                context = json.dumps({'success': False,
                                      'error': 'Method %s cannot be called due to %s.' % (method,
                                                                                          str(e))})
        else:
            context = json.dumps({'success': False,
                                  'error': 'No method specified'})

        return HttpResponse(context, content_type="json/application")

    def get_attributes(self, request):
        attributes = ListOfAttributes.objects.filter(
            item__id=request.POST.get('item'))
        json_op = []
        for attribute in attributes:
            json_op.append({"id": attribute.id,
                            "name": attribute.name})
        return json.dumps(json_op)
```

**The same JQuery script is used in both insert and edit views/forms, but it works only for insertion, and not edition.** When I looked into the data, the insertion properly asks the server for

```
http://the_server/app/insert_ajax
```

so the server responds, and the drop-down list for Attributes is filtered and modified accordingly. But in the edition view it does not work, and when I looked into what ajax asks the server for, it came out like this:

```
http://the_server/app/edit/2453/insert_ajax
```

which is, of course, wrong, so the script won't receive any data and will not modify anything (it just leaves ALL data in drop-down list).

So my question is: why is this happening and how can I fix it? How can I make this script works in both - edition and insertion views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it!

I had to change urls.py and add another line:

```
url(r'^app/insert$', Insert.as_view(), name="insert"),
url(r'^app/insert_ajax$', Insert_Ajax.as_view(), name="insert_ajax"),
url(r'^app/edit/(?P<id>\d+)$', Edit.as_view(), name="edit"),
url(r'^app/edit/insert_ajax$', Insert_Ajax.as_view(), name="insert_insert_ajax"),
```

So now that script can be called within edit, and it will find it's way back to the same view handler Insert_Ajax.

Also I had to modify the JQuery script, so that it runs BOTH calls - to insert_ajax, and insert_insert_ajax:

```
var post_change = function(){

    var selected_id = $("#selected_id").val();
    $.post("insert_ajax",{"method":"get_attributes","item":$("#id_item").val()}, change_item);
    $.post("insert_edit_ajax",{"method":"get_attributes","item":$("#id_item").val()}, change_item);
}
```

and throw out the response handler to a different function "change_item" (so I don't have to copy+paste the code.

And it works! Not a very elegant solution with that redundant calls to both views together hoping one of them responds, but for now it'll do. Maybe I'll change it later when I learn how to check if the URL call was a success.

Answer (score 1):

I Assume that `/app/edit/2453/` is a viewable url.

When you edit contents from that `/app/edit/2453/`, JQuery fires an AJAX POST request to `url` + `insert_ajax`.

See this line:

```
$.post("insert_ajax",{"method":"get_attributes","item......
```

You can fix the behavior by replacing "insert_ajax" with full relative url (`/app/edit/2453/`) for the edit page.

Comment: That's what I thought, but in that case, the full address of ajax while insertion should be /app/insert/insert_ajax, but that's not the case - it's /app/insert_ajax, so it puzzles me WHY it appends the insert_ajax at the end of edition.
Did I mention, that all views are in the same file? Does it change anything?
Also, I tried to just give a full app URL instead of just django name, but it just appends the whole address to the edition URL...

Comment: It happens because unlike the edit url, other urls _DO NOT_ end with `/`.  When the urls do not end with forward slash, the current page (last part of url) gets replaced by `insert_ajax`. Avoid mixing of forward slash url endings.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. But there's that problem, that the number is actually an item's id number from database. Now I'm thinking how to fix this, since the first launch is with get method, so the data must be somehow sent/handled/displayed.